# Why my ajax kept jumping in error function?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

```js
This is the code, first time using starckoverflow please be kind haha.

function UpdateEvent() {
    var _IDe = document.getElementById('EvID').value;
    var _Header = document.getElementById('Eheader').value;
    var _Body = document.getElementById('Ebody').value;
    var _Date = document.getElementById('Edate').value;
    var _EventPic = document.getElementById('ImgEvent').value;

    var dat = new FormData($('ImgEven')[0]);
  /*  dat.append("idE", _IDe);
    dat.append("header", _Header);
    dat.append("body", _Body);
    dat.append("date", _Date);
    dat.append("ae", _EventPic);*/
    
 
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '/Portal/UpdateEvent',
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: { idE: _IDe, header: _Header, body: _Body, date: _Date, ae: dat },
        success: function () {
            alert("OK");
            msgS.innerHTML = "Update Succesful";
            $("#SuccessAlertEvent").modal('show');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("No");
            msgE.innerHTML = "Error";
            $("#ErrorAlertEvent").modal('show');
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert('Run');
        }

    });


}
```

```css
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateEvent(int idE, string header, string body, string date, AddEvents 
ae)
        {
            db er = new db();
            byte[] data = ConvertToBytes(ae.EventPicture);
            er.Adm_UpdateTimeline(idE, header, body, Convert.ToDateTime(date), data);
            return RedirectToAction("AddEvent", "Portal");
        }
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEvent", "Portal" , FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                        {

                            
                                
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ID, new { @class = "form-control", @type =                                  "text", @id = "EvID", @hidden = "hidden", @readonly = "readonly" })

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Header, new { @class = "form-control", @type =                       "text", @placeholder = "Header", @required = "required", @id = "Eheader" })


                                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Body, new { @class = "form-control",     @placeholder = "Body", @required = "required", @id = "Ebody", @rows = "10", @style = "resize:none;" })


                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Date, new { @class = "form-control", @type =                           "date", @placeholder = "Date", @required = "required", @id = "Edate" })

                                
                                    
                                        
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EventPicture, new { @type = "file",                         @class = "custom-file-input", @id = "ImgEvent" })
                                            Choose file
                                        
                                    
                                


                                
                                    
                                        Save
                                    
                                    
                                        Update
                                    
                                    
                                        Cancel
                                    
                                
                            
                        }
```

Comment: When it is going to the error function, what is the exception/error message you are getting? Your question has severe formatting issues. You must spend time to formulate you question in a clear manner with enough details.

Comment: wow ... that's some heavy handed indentation

Comment: When i clicked the save button, I dont getting any exception message, but it is jumping in error function, i think the problem is when im passing the value to my paramaters, but im not so sure.

Comment: Wahahaha sorry about that, i left a message at the top of my code though -_- this is my firstime using stackoverflow

Comment: set breakpoints and see whether the API is hit and check the arguments passed to it are mapped correctly. Most probably there is an error in your API method.

Comment: Found out the problem, /*  var _EventPic = document.getElementById('ImgEvent').value; */ we we're getting an error here, so we tried this query instead and it worked /*   var fle = $('#ImgEvent').get(0).files;*/